# Node Soap - http get request return index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-soap

I am using https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap a soap client and server for node.js

I have created my own SOAP server. The client can execute methods on the SOAP server and the server sends a response to the client which match the appropriate client expectation.

Code snippet:

```
const myService = {
SubsystemProductionService: {
    SubsystemProductionServicePort: {
    ...
    }}};

const wsdlxml = fs.readFileSync('./my.wsdl', 'utf8'),
server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {        
    response.end("404: Not Found: " + request.url);
});

// example call: PORT=9999 node app.js

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(PORT);
console.log('server running on port ' + PORT);
soap.listen(server, '/myService', myService, wsdlxml);
```

But, before the client execute a method on the SOAP server the client send a HTTP GET request and expected a response such as:

*HTTP Status Code 200 + index.html*

The trouble is, that my SOAP service response:

*HTTP Status Code 200 + empty body*.

Every HTTP GET request to /myService will be handled by soap module and it seems that *HTTP Status Code 200 + empty body* is the default case.

How can i change the behaviour of the soap service to return:

*HTTP Status Code 200 + index.html*

instead of

*HTTP Status Code 200 + empty body*

in response to a HTTP GET request?

Best regards